# undefined method `stripe' for # <Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am trying to do my first test order through Stripe on my Rails app that I'm testing out but I'm getting a NoMethodError - undefined method `stripe' for #, exact line that's causing it is in a JS snippet on my form order file.

Edit: Adding screenshot of the error, changing Rails.configuration.stripe to Rails.application.secrets lets the page load but the checkout is throwing another error (screenshot also attached)

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZsxY.png)
[publishable error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL4ec.png)

```js
< script >
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: '<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>',
    token: function(token, arg) {
      document.getElementById("stripeToken").value = token.id;
      document.getElementById("stripeEmail").value = token.email;
      document.getElementById("chargeForm").submit();
    }
  });

document.getElementById('btn-order').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
  var total_price = (quantity * "<%= @meal.price %>") + "00";
  $('#total_price').val(total_price);
  handler.open({
    name: "Sixerr",
    description: "<%= @meal.title %>",
    amount: total_price
  });
  e.preventDefault();
}); < /script>
```

And here is my stripe.rb file

```html
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  :secret_key      => ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

There was a couple other answers but none of them seemed to fix the problem, appreciate any help here.

Comment: Is your stripe.rb file in your initializers folder?  And did you restart your webserver after adding it?

Comment: Also can you add the full error stack?

Comment: @danielrsmith holy crap that was totally it, thank you so much!

Comment: @WinLin Added the answer for you to accept and upvote.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure that your `stripe.rb` file is in the `config/initializers` folder, and once that is done, you need to restart your webserver so that the initializer can be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the file is present in the config/initializers folder, 
below is the configuration for stripe.rb file

```
     if Rails.env.development?
        Rails.configuration.stripe = {
            :publishable_key => 'pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            :secret_key      => 'sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
        end
Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]

    if Rails.env.production?
      Rails.configuration.stripe = {
          :publishable_key => 'pk_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          :secret_key      => 'sk_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      }

    end

    if Rails.env.test?
      Rails.configuration.stripe = {
          :publishable_key => 'pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          :secret_key      => 'sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      }
    end
    Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```